# strncpy causing LPC-2378 to hang/die

Tags: c, embedded, strncpy

I'm doing some work on an Olimex LPC2378-STK.

I have the following declaration.

```
unsigned char buffer[256];
```

I then attempt to do:

```
strncpy((char *)buffer, "CREATED_BY", 255);
```

Does anyone know why this would cause an issue.

If i comment out the line of code it runs without issue but using it seems to cause the program to die.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `strncpy` here. You might avoid potential  buffer overflow but, it he buffer isn't big enough, you will end up with different problem. It doesn't look like it's the cause of the problem though.

Comment: I don't see an issue with this, other then the pointlessness of it. If you're going to use `strncpy()` you need to remember that it **always writes N chars, where N is the last parameter.**. If the source string length, including the null-terminator, is less than N, then it will backfill the remaining  space out to N with 0's. If it is longer, it will copy up to N chars out, and NOT set the last char to 0. But it *always* writes N chars one way or another. I think you may have another issue somewhere that is overrunning into *this* buffer and possibly that 0-clear is exposing that problem.

Comment: Thanks guys I was scratching my head wondering. The point about something else ovrrunning is good. Given the restrictions of the board and stack space this is possibly the issue. Fun times debugging ahead.

Comment: try to decrease buffer size to the minimal enough

Comment: wait a moment - you have buffer array ON STACK?

Comment: No, don't worry I'm not a lunatic I was thinking about something else when i wrote that. I've been looking at a variety of code all day. They've kind of blended together.

Comment: @WhozCraig:  While `strncpy()` is not defined as part of the ANSI standard library, so an  implementation might do as it likes, I have never come across an implementation that "will backfill the remaining space".

Comment: @Clifford Really? Because according to the standard, **C9899 §7.23.2.4,p3** *"If the array pointed to by s2 is a string that is shorter than n characters, null characters are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by s1, until n characters in all have been written."*. Every library I've ever used that claimed compliance with the standard does this, so I'm not sure what library *you're* using.

Comment: @WozCraig:  Gaa!  I was about to delete my comment, and you had to go and answer!  I take it back.  It did not exist in C89, and many embedded systems tools other than those GCC based have been slow to support C99, and *perhaps* libraries that pre-date C99 copy *upto* N characters.  In a microcontroller that would certainly be optimal.  However I am no longer so certain!

Comment: @Clifford I could certainly see some implementations skirting around parts of the standard, especially in an embedded system. No biggee. They're just not standard-conforming, in which case you'd be absolutely right (about this function, and anything else they chose to turn a blind eye to); They can do as they please. I would hope if this is so, they at least *don't* claim conformance with the standard though, or what would be the point of it? =P I try to stay in those confines (the standard) where possible, but embedded folks often play by "interesting" rules. (as in, sometimes they don't).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with the code you have posted, but it is without context.  For example if `buffer[]` is a local variable, it will be created on the stack, and it is possible that you are overflowing the stack.

You might declare it static to see if the problem goes away which would verify a stack overflow.  If the variable needs to be temporary, then you will need to allocate a suitably larger stack.

Note that the stack overflow may not occur specifically at the strncpy. `buffer` may be contained within the stack, but its size may have pushed other objects beyond the stack so that writing to *them* causes stack corruption.  The point of failure is usually when a function tries to return using a corrupted return address.  You should really use a debugger to step the code to see what is going on with the call stack, the stack pointer and whether the function fails on the strncpy or rather when the calling function returns.

One point about code safety and maintainability, you should prefer:

```
strncpy((char *)buffer, "CREATED_BY", sizeof(buffer) - 1);
```

You could also more conveniently use an initialiser:

```
unsigned char buffer[256] = "CREATED_BY" ;
```

Comment: +1 I think he's definitely overflowing something, hard saying what. Speculation is something else was "working" by borrowing that space in that buffer via UB, and the `strncpy()` (with its tail-fill.. =P <jab>) walked over the mystery goo that was there.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of things can go wrong with strncpy:

1. You are trying to write to memory you have not allocated, has the NULL address, or you have no permission to (the cast to `char *` is highly suspicious),
2. Your buffer contents are not NUL-terminated
3. You are overflowing your buffer, overwriting something.

Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with the same issue you are reporting.

What happened to me is that I had not configured the startup code (if using keil) to reserve space for the HEAP memory. The printf family function uses malloc and free, so, HEAP space is mandatory.

If you are using GCC, the problem is that you have not setup the newlib properly. Check the heap.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I actually fixed the issue it was a conflict between an extra library I no longer needed and a sha-256 implementation.

Comment: Yes, that can be an issue with many functions on bare metal embedded targes, but strncpy is neither a "printf family function" nor one that should be allocating memory.

Comment: Very clever @ChrisStratton, I did not note the confusion I made. Thanks.